# Computed property in model not being returned by controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using .Net Core Entity Framework for a test application for a sciene experiment.

I have the following model that is used in one of our EF controllers.

This model has a computed property called `fuelBurnPerSecond` that uses other properties for a calculation.

This computed property is not in the database(and I can't add it because it's a very old DB).

Anyway, when I hit the controllers `GET` method to get a list of all the `RocketTestProtocols`, I don't see `fuelBurnPerSecond` in the returned JSON. I see everything else, but not the computed property.

I am getting no error though.

Here is the model:

```
public partial class RocketTestProtocols
{
    public int EngineMass { get; set; }
    public int FuelVolume { get; set; }
    public WeatherStations WeatherStation { get; set; }
    
    public int fuelBurnPerSecond = ((EngineMass * 0.2) * (FuelVolume * 1.9) / WeatherStation.VelocityWave);
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<RocketTestProtocols>>> GetRocketTestProtocols()
    {
        return await _context.RocketTestProtocols.ToListAsync();
    }
```

How can I get the controller to return the computed property `fuelBurnPerSecond`?

Thanks!

Comment: The property has to be sent by the server which creates the response.  The response is what the controller parses to make the classes.

Comment: Can  you show your controller action pls?

Comment: Maybe it's not a good idea, but that field it's the only one that is not a property. You should try change it for `public int fuelBurnPerSecond { get { return ((EngineMass * 0.2) * (FuelVolume * 1.9) / WeatherStation.VelocityWave); }`

Comment: @jdweng thanks, do you mean sent by the controller?  I added the controller code to my question.  The controller sends every other property back, just not the computed property. Do I need do add something to my controller?  Thanks!

Comment: @Sergey I just added my GET controller

Comment: With HTTP your sent a request from the client and get a response back from the server.  The controller parses the response in the Task<ActionResult>.  The response has have the RocketTestProtocols as the root of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add [NotMapped] attribute to this property, or use fluent Api ignore:

```
[NotMapped]
public int fuelBurnPerSecond 
{
    get { return ... your code }
}

//or in dbcontext

 modelBuilder.Entity<RocketTestProtocols>().Ignore(c => c.fuelBurnPerSecond );
```

And  by the way, try to fix your class too:

```
public partial class RocketTestProtocols
{
   ....
    public int WeatherStationId { get; set; }
    public WeatherStations WeatherStation { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fuelBurnPerSecond` in your model is declared as a field, not as a property. Entity Framework Core does not include fields in models returned as query result.

Change `fuelBurnPerSecond` to a property, a read-only one since you'll never set value to this property -

```
public int FuelBurnPerSecond
{
    get { return (EngineMass * 0.2) * (FuelVolume * 1.9) / WeatherStation.VelocityWave; }
}
```

Comment: When I did that, I get an error saying, `property or indexer must have at least one accessor`

Comment: Maybe you are having any typo. `at least one accessor` is already there, the `get` accessor.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Have you replaced the `fuelBurnPerSecond` field with the property above?